# redrawing square every 100 ms but it doesn't move smoothly

Tags: javascript, canvas

i have a window event listener. when i click it, it fires the "condition" function which determines the next coordinates of the square if i click anywhere on the window. if i don't click nothing happens.

Then it fires the draw function which repeats every 100 Millisecond which draws the square.so whenever i click on canvas the square moves based on where i click my mouse.

my question is the draw function repeats every 100 Millisecond so why doesn't the square move smoothly whenever i click on the canvas to make the square move.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const c = canvas.getContext('2d');

// coords
let ballX = canvas.width / 2;
let ballY = 300;
let ballHeight = 50;
let ballThiccness = 50;

//draw one time
draw();

window.addEventListener('click' , function(e) {
 condition(e); // passing window e parameter to get e.clientX.
 function execute() {draw()}
 let interval = setInterval(execute , 100);
});

// determine next coordinates of square
function condition(e) {
 let mouseX = e.clientX;
 let mouseY = e.clientY;
 if (mouseY > ballY && mouseY < ballY + ballHeight && mouseX < ballX) {
  ballX += ballX - mouseX;
  return false;
 } else if (mouseY > ballY && mouseY < ballY + ballHeight && mouseX > ballX) {
  ballX += ballX - mouseX;
  return false;
 }
 if (mouseX > ballX && mouseX < ballX + ballThiccness && mouseY < ballY) {
  ballY += ballY - mouseY;
  return false;
 } else if (mouseX > ballX && mouseX < ballX + ballThiccness && mouseY > ballY) {
  ballY += ballY - mouseY;
  return false;
 }
 ballX += ballX - mouseX;
 ballY += ballY - mouseY;
}

function draw() {
 c.clearRect(0 , 0 , canvas.width , canvas.height);
 c.fillStyle = 'black';
 c.fillRect(0,0 , 800 , 600);
 c.fillStyle = 'dodgerblue';
 c.fillRect(ballX, ballY , ballThiccness, ballHeight);
}
```

```html
<canvas height="600" width="800"></canvas>
```

i expect the square to move smoother when i click on window but it doesn't.

Comment: What do you mean when you expect it to move smoother? There's only one movement taking place per click. Also, notice that you're not resetting your interval each time you click - it's going to keep adding new intervals, which will causing the drawing to happen more and more frequently. On that note, if movement is only happening on click, why are you using an interval in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that by smooth movement, you mean the box to animate to its target position. From your implementation, I think you are assuming the canvas to behave like CSS animation. But JavaScript canvas is very different; you have to code your animations completely.

In order to make the box animate to the final position, you have to increase(or decrease) the value of its coordinates by certain amount.

I have implemented the code for the box to move on horizontal axis.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

class Box {
  constructor (x, y, width, height, speed) {
    this.x = x; //position of the box
    this.y = y;
    this.w = width; //box width
    this.h = height; //box height
    this.speed = speed; //this is the factor that defines how fast the box will be moving on the canvas
  }
  
  show() { //draw the box on canvas
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
  }
  
  move(target) { 

//Check if the box is on target. If not, add/subtract the speed on the axes value.
    if(target - this.x < 0 && this.x > target) {
      this.x -= this.speed;
    }
    if(target - this.x > 0 && this.x < target) {
      this.x += this.speed;
    }
  
  }
}

let box = new Box(100, 20, 50, 50, 1); //instantiate a new Box
let target = box.x; //initially set the target equal to the box position

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle="#000";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  box.move(target);
  box.show();
  requestAnimationFrame(draw); //this creates a loop which enables animation
}

canvas.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
//update tha value of target based on the position of mouse click
  target = (2 * box.x) - e.clientX;
  draw();
});

draw();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```